# Need to join 2 tables using substring of different lengths on one column with length stated in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to join 2 tables of which I need to substring a column in Table 1. What is unknown is the length of the substring in order to join to Table 2.  The first few numbers are the joining key with differing lengths. Table 2 does state the length and will be the indicator on which entries need to be substringed with a specific length. The second table has fixed length of 9 so will also need to be substringed (which will be easy to do). Table 1 is my problem. The length column in Table 2 tells you how much of the ShortRef to use as well as how much to substring RefNr in Table1 which then becomes the join. However, I am not sure how to do this in SSMS or whether it is possible.

Since table 2 informs how much to substring, I currently don't see a solution and I don't know if like will work or how to do this using like.

Example:

```
TABLE 1
|RefNr           |
|----------------|
|1234567890101234|
|9876543210090876|
|1234569000100223|

TABLE 2
|ShortRef | Length | Name |
|---------|--------|------|
|123456789|8       |Alice |  
|123456909|8       |Cindy |
|987654999|6       |Ben   |

RESULTS SHOULD BE:
|RefNr           | Substr Table1&2 based on Length in Table2 | Name |
|----------------|-------------------------------------------|------|
|1234567890101234| 12345678                                  |Alice |                                                            
|9876543210090876| 987654                                    |Ben   |                                                                     
|1234569000100223| 12345690                                  |Cindy |
```

[EXAMPLE OF TABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny0Fg.png)

Comment: What are you asking here?

Comment: I want to know how do I use Table 2 length column to tell me how much to substring Table 1 RefNr when it looks similar to Table2 ShortRef and once done, join the 2 tables. Please see example image.

Comment: Take the time to post the same data, in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statements but at least well formatted `text`. Same for your expected results. Don't forget, as well, to include *your* attempts and explain why they didn't work too,.

Comment: I will try add the tables too, however, the final version didn't post well. Also, I wish I could try post attempts, I just cannot think of any way to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're wanting this exactly, but i took correct output for the example table with this.

```
SELECT RefNr
      ,tb2."Substring Table1 based on length in Table2"
      ,tb2.Name
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SUBSTRING(ShortRef, 0, Length+1) as "Substring Table1 based on length in Table2",
        Name,
        Length
 FROM Table2) as tb2
ON SUBSTRING(RefNr, 0, tb2.Length + 1) = tb2."Substring Table1 based on length in Table2"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! If possible, can you please advise the logic on what helps it know which RefNr relates to which ShortRef number to know what length to use?

Comment: I used a sub query named tb2 to fetch substrings of ShortRef with length and name columns. And I used the same length values with tb2.Length in ON statement to pair the substrings that i fetched from tb2 and the ones from table1. I hope I explained good enough if I understood your your question right.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to join the tables together with string operations:

```
select t1.*, left(t2.refnr, t2.length), t2.name
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on left(t2.refnr, t2.length) = left(t1.refnr, t2.length);
```